# Appending New Object to the existing file

Tags: java, object, serialization, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

Hi I have an issue when trying to append  new objects to the existing file..
Once the  android app has been lunched again I want to get the existing file and add a new objects then read the objects from the existing file ... Actually, when I'm trying to read the object, the code will read only the first objects .. You can find below the code .. Could you please help ? Thanks

using the following method to write an objects :

```
 public void saveObject(Person p, File f){
     try
     {

         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f, true));
         oos.writeObject(p);
         oos.reset();
         oos.flush(); 
         oos.close();


     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        Log.v("Serialization Save Error : ",ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Using the following method to read an objects :

```
    public Object loadSerializedObject(File f)
{

       try {
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
           try{
              Object loadedObj = null;
              while ((loadedObj = ois.readObject()) != null) {
              Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "ReadingObjects") ;

            }
              return objects;
           }finally{
               ois.close();
           }

       } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
}
```

Comment: When you *return objects*: where is **objects** declared? where do you assing any value to **objects**?

Comment: Could it be that you're writing different objects to different files and if so are you actually fetching all objects you've written to files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't create a new `ObjectOutputStream` every time you want to append to the stream and then read everything back with a single stream. The [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29) adds headers to the underlying stream before you start writing objects. You are probably seeing the `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC` exception, that's because the first header is `0xAC`.

I don't know how many objects you are dealing with, but one option might be to read all your objects and then rewriting them all using a single `ObjectOutputStream`. That can get pricy if there are lots of objects. Alternatively, you might want to consider managing the serialization yourself manually through [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html). It can get painful though.